# Deploying contracts in Ropsten with Truffle

Tags: truffle, contract-deployment, ropsten, truffle-migration

I have another n00b question... sorry about that :(

I'm trying to deploy a smart contract to Ropsten. I have synched the Ropsten network with `geth --testnet --fast --rpc --rpcapi eth,net,web3,personal`, and it looks perfectly up to date.

Then I try to deploy that smart contract (which I've already deployed to my private testrpc network and it works poerfectly) to Ropsten. To do so I'm executing `truffle migrate --network ropsten` and I'm getting this pesky error:

```
Could not connect to your Ethereum client. Please check that your Ethereum client:
    - is running
    - is accepting RPC connections (i.e., "--rpc" option is used in geth)
    - is accessible over the network
    - is properly configured in your Truffle configuration file (truffle.js)
```

The geth instance is in fact up and running, since I can connect to it with `geth attach http://127.0.0.1:8545` and it works fine. It is accepting connections, since I used the --rpc option. It is accessible over the network because I've already accessed it... and I think than my Truffle configuration file is ok, here's how it looks:

```
require('babel-register')

module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 8545,
      network_id: '*' // Match any network id
    },
    ropsten: {
      host: "localhost",
      port: 8545,
      network_id: "3",
    }
  }
}
```

Can anyone please tell me why am I getting this error and what can I do to fix it?

Thank you so much in advance!!! :)

Comment: if i add from field it returns invalid address but if i remove the from field it gets stuck

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20199)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When I was deploying my contract through truffle in rinkeby network I too got the same error after adding from address and gas it got deployed. Try this

```
networks: {
  ropsten: {
    network_id: 3,
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 8545,
    gas: 4000000,
    from: <your unlocked ropsten account address>
  },
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Jazz!
Well, looks a bit better, now I get this 2 new lines, but still it fails :(
--->Using network 'ropsten'.
--->Running migration: 1_initial_migration.js
Could not connect to your Ethereum client (etc...)

Comment: Ok, looks like the problem might be that my blockchain database has been corrupted, so I need to synchronize again... Aaaarrgghhh!!

Comment: It finally worked, thanks a lot!! :) It's important to note that the only contents of truffle.js must be what you wrote... I had to remove another network I had configured in that file so this whole thing could work.

Comment: You could also use following command to specifically use a network, if you have multiple networks configured.

    truffle migrate --network ropsten

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to get your ropsten account unlocked. You might opt for private key deployment. I've build lib for something like this.

```
const etherlime = require('etherlime');

const ICOTokenContract = require('./build/contracts/ICOToken.json');

const randomAddress = '0xda8a06f1c910cab18ad187be1faa2b8606c2ec86';

const defaultConfigs = {
    gasPrice: 20000000000,
    gasLimit: 4700000
}

const deployer = new etherlime.InfuraPrivateKeyDeployer('Your Privste KEY', 'ropsten', 'Your infura API key', defaultConfigs);

const runICODeployment = async () => {
    const contractWrapper = await deployer.deploy(ICOTokenContract);
    const transferTransaction = await contractWrapper.contract.transferOwnership(randomAddress);
    const result = await contractWrapper.verboseWaitForTransaction(transferTransaction.hash, 'Transfer Ownership');
}
runICODeployment()
```

Place this in a simple js file and run it with node. Hope this helps.